# About finding a real $w$ such that if $k≥w$ then $p_{k}≥c$

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $p_{k}$ be the sequence of prime numbers.

Assume that we have an inequality of the form $p_{k}≥c$ where $c$ is real number.

My **question** is about finding a real $w$ such that if $k≥w$ then $p_{k}≥c$

I am aware about the fact that the prime counting function is an inverse of $p_{k}$. But I am not able to use it.

Comment: Why not let $w=\frac12(c+1)$? Then if $k\ge w$, we have $p_k\ge 2w-1=c$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: How we can prove this statement